# Extract multiple lines between two variables

Tags: regex, powershell

I am stuck in a code, my requirement is to get the lines between two strings(variables), please suggest a regex pattern

Input:

```
Device Name: test
Status: Completed
Results:
[PUSH_TERMLET] Action completed successfully...
Pushing configuration file 'PUSH_TERMLET' for IDX 60504 with mechanism SSH
****** Enable Mode Results ******
sh run | sec ip access-list standard customer_internal
ip access-list standard customer_internal
 permit 204.79.49.116
 permit 159.12.130.0 0.0.0.31
 permit 10.108.30.0 0.0.0.255
 permit 10.108.141.0 0.0.0.127
 permit 10.108.172.0 0.0.0.255
 permit 10.108.160.0 0.0.0.31
test#
```

Output:

```
 permit 204.79.49.116
 permit 159.12.130.0 0.0.0.31
 permit 10.108.30.0 0.0.0.255
 permit 10.108.141.0 0.0.0.127
 permit 10.108.172.0 0.0.0.255
 permit 10.108.160.0 0.0.0.31
```

Here is the code that i am  trying

```
$content = Get-Content -Path "TestACL.txt"

$device_list = $content | Select-String -Pattern "device name" -AllMatches

foreach($temp in $device_list) {
    $temp.sp
    $pattern = "(?<=$temp|permit)(.*)"
    $content | Select-String -Pattern $pattern
}
```

Apart from that i tried other patterns also, none of them worked for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your regex was kinda close. Lets explore this option.

```
$Content = (Get-Content "C:\temp\TestACL.txt") -join ' '
$variable = "test#"
$Output = ($Content  | Select-String -Pattern "(?:permit )(.*)(?= $($variable))").Matches.Value
```

`(?:permit )` will find the word `permit`, space inclusive, and the `?:` will include it in the match.

`(?= test#)` will fing the word `test#`, space inclusive, and the `?=` will match but exclude it from results after the main expression.

The `(.*)` will capture anything between the first and last criteria

Comment: You should IMO undo the join by appending `-split '  (?=permit)'`

Comment: @Drew Thank you for the answer! It works for me. Is it possible to use test# as a variable in regex pattern. Please suggest

Comment: @KomalB I have updated my answer with the ability to use a variable instead of `test#`